# Why does TCP buffers size are fixed and is not dynamically being reallocated based on user demand ?

Tags: tcp, buffer

According to TCP flow control , after successful tcp handshake, both client and server will allocate buffers and variables . Generally buffer side would be either 4096 or 8192 .
Why cannot  TCP dynamically increase the already allocated the size.
I mean it can increase the buffer size from 4096 to 8192 or 8192 to 17000 bytes depending on what user demands .

Say if user demands 81920 bytes of a file , it gets split into 10 chunks of data and these are buffered into send buffer before sending it to client . Why cant it check,
if file size > buffer size ,
double the buffer size.
By this it can send 5 chunks of data instead of 10 , there by saving time .

Comment: You can set both send and receive buffer sizes yourself with the `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF` socket options. But that only matter for copying data *locally*, as the limit to what can send and receive in a single packet is the lowest MTU in the network.

Comment: First, this is  off-topic and more on-topic at [networkengineering.se]. Apart from that the claim is wrong: the buffers are dynamic in modern system but they are limited on how much they can grow and this limit can be tuned system wide and also per socket.

Comment: I agree that buffers are dynamic in modern system . They are allocated using malloc (as per my knowledge on socket programming using c). But my question was why cannot somebody use realloc and then vary the memory allocated for buffers according to the data that need to be sent .